# Script executes loop only once

Tags: shell-script

I am using this script on router using Entware to check response of website every 15 min. It only runs once and terminates after the first 15 mins. Why?

```
#! /bin/sh

for i in {1..10}
do  
  date >> webresp.csv
  curl -w 'Testing Website Response Time for :%{url_effective}\n\nLookup Time:\t\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect Time:\t\t%{time_connect}\nPre-transfer Time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStart-transfer Time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal Time:\t\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null www.google.com | tee -a webresp.csv
  sleep 900
done
```

Comment: If want your script to check the server every 15 minutes, why run it only 10 times? Do you use another script to start it every 2 and a half hours? Why not use cron?

Comment: @mosvy The 10 times was only for test run..I would adjust according to my needs when script works. Will try as cron as well but had problems before..confusing quotation marks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
for i in {1..10}
```

to this:

```
for i in $(seq 10)
```

...and the script should then work as expected.

Comment: @agc...thanks..that worked! Thanks all script is working now.

Comment: @kielan, See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 11):

You are using `#! /bin/sh`. `{1..10}` is a bash extension, not standard shell. Bash would expand `{1..10}` into 10 words,for a standard shell it is just one word.